# I can't write on or react to id="Main"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't get whether this is a CSS problem or a JS problem...
After I was messing with my code, I couldn't react to the id Main part.
I had an input there, but can't write anything.
I don't think that CSS is the problem because I didn't change significant things on there.
I thought JS was a problem but can't find any.

```js
// function declaration

function checkChange(a) {
  if (a == 0) {
    main.style.marginLeft = "0%";
    main.style.paddingTop = "20px";
  } else if (a == 1) {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 600) {
      main.style.marginLeft = "0%";
      main.style.paddingTop = "150px";
    } else {
      main.style.marginLeft = "25%";
      main.style.paddingTop = "20px";
    }
  } else if (a == 2) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 600) {
      main.style.marginLeft = "25%";
      main.style.paddingTop = "20px";
    } else {
      main.style.marginLeft = "0%";
      main.style.paddingTop = "150px";
    }
  }
}



function resize() {
  if (check == true) {
        menuBar.style.width = "0%";
        num = 0;
        check = false;
      } else {
        if (window.innerWidth > 600) {
          menuBar.style.width = "100%";
          num = 1;
        } else if (window.innerWidth <= 600) {
          menuBar.style.width = "100%";
          num = 2;
        }
        check = true;
      }  
      checkChange(num);
};





// start of the program

const modal = document.getElementById("modal");
const menuBar = document.getElementById("Menu");
const main = document.getElementById("Main");
let check;
let num;

check = true;


// start of main

// User Interface Click and Changes

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    resize();
  }
});

// check whether resize is detected
$(window).resize(function() {
  checkChange(num);
});
// 

// Check whether variable check is true or false
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 36) {
    alert(check);
  }
});

// end of main


// User Interface Alert
alert("Click Enter to close or open Menu Bar");

//end of the program
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}


#Menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: block; 
  transition: 0.3s;  /* Stay in place */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
}


#modal {
  height: 100%; 
  width: 25%; 
  padding-top: 60px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 2px solid #3a3a3a;
  z-index: 1; 
  background-color: #111;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  transition: 0.3s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


#modal::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none; 
}


.cover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 8px;
  margin: 15px;
  font-size: 3vw;
  color: #818181;
  border: 1px solid white;
}


.cover:hover {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  cursor: pointer;
}


#Main {
  margin-left: 25%;
  transition: .25s; 
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #modal {
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
  }


  #Main {
    padding-top: 150px;
    margin-left: 0%;
  }


  .cover {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 23px;
  }
}


.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none; 
  user-select: none; 
}


@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  #Main {
    margin-left: 25%;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>




  
  <body>
    <div id="Menu">
      <div id="modal">
        <div id="rpc" class="cover noselect">Rock-Scissor<br />-Paper</div>
        <div class="cover noselect"></div>
        <div class="cover noselect"></div>
        <div class="cover noselect"></div>
      </div>
    </div>  




    <div id="Main">
      <div><input type="text" /></div>
    </div>





    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="control.js" defer></script>
    <script type="module" src="RPC.js" defer></script>
    <script src="hello.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by saying "I have input there"? `<div>` is not an `<input>`

Comment: Did you mean to make the divs editable? Or did you mean to have input elements rather than divs?

Comment: if you want the `div` to be editable without using `input` use: `<div contenteditable="true"></div>`

Comment: I mean I had input there before. Which really isn't significant btw. The problem with my code is that I can't highlight words, and if there is input, I can't put anything in.

Comment: you can't highlight only in main div or all document? check in F12 maybe you have some css or js that block editing (check it by try to change the id name from "Main" to something else)

Comment: Still, I can't highlight any. I've changed the snippet "Main" part to input.

Comment: did you try change the `id` name from `Main` to something else?

Comment: Yeah I have tried. I found out the problem certainly. If I click enter and resize the menuBar, I can write on input, but I can't write anything if the menuBar is shown. I don't get the reason :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div id="Main" />` set without `position` style in your css. That is mean, that this div has a default value for `position` which equals to `static`. Static element ignored any position specific property (left, top, z-index). `Menu` component overlap `Main` component, and because of `position: static`, `Main` rendered under `Menu`. To fix that, just add any `position` value, exluding `static`. I think `relative` will be fill all your needs.

```css
#Main {
  margin-left: 25%;
  transition: .25s; 
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```